# Boolean shortcircuit evaluation in Linq lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have the following Linq lambda expression:

```
private IEnumerable<SubjectSelectorSubjectGroup> GetSubjectList()
{
    User user = db.Users.Find(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
    return db.RequiredSubjects.Where(r => !r.Subject.Name.Contains("Home"))
                              .GroupBy(r => r.Subject)
                              .OrderByDescending(r => r.Count())
                              .Select(r => new SubjectSelectorSubjectGroup()
                              {
                                  SubjectId = r.Key.SubjectId,
                                  SubjectName = r.Key.Name,
                                  IsInFavourites = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated &&
                                                  (user.Elective1 != null && user.Elective1.SubjectId == r.Key.SubjectId ||
                                                   user.Elective2 != null && user.Elective2.SubjectId == r.Key.SubjectId ||
                                                   user.Elective3 != null && user.Elective3.SubjectId == r.Key.SubjectId),
                                  Occurrences = r.Count()
                              });
}
```

When the user is not logged in then the `user` variable in this function is null. This should not be a problem becuase short-circuit boolean evaluation *should* deal with this. The problem is, it doesn't! Instead, a `System.NullReferenceException` is thrown.

When the user is null `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated` returns false. I have checked this by commenting out the bracketed section that references the `user` variable, and then expression evaluates correctly.

Does anyone know why `Linq to Sql` tries to dereference the `user` variable in this situation when it shouldn't actually be necessary? Does anyone have a work around for this issue?

Comment: `NullReferenceException` is thrown when a reference is null _in memory_. That indicates that a part of this query is not translated to SQL but is evaluated in memory. Can you check the SQL query that is emitted? The culprit should be in the part that is not translated to SQL.

Comment: Hi Gert. I have already resolved this by creating a List<string>. But just as a matter of interest, how do I check the SQL query that is emitted? I am new to Linq so still tring to figure this stuff out. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You can use [DataContext.Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx), or the Sql profiler of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The entire expression is translated to and evaluated as SQL, which means that the `&&` operator is not short circuited as expected.

You can solve the problem by building a list or array of the `ElectiveX.SubjectId` that you want to search for and then use `tmpList.Contains(r.Key.SubjectId)` in the query. That will be translated into a `WHERE IN (...)` SQL expression.

Comment: Thanks, Anders, for the explanation and the suggestion to use a list. I resolved it using a list as you suggested. I will put the code the code for my solution in a separate answer, but will mark your answer as correct. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I also observed that short circuiting doesn't work as expected. I don't think the fact that a C# expression is translated to SQL, under the hood, dismisses Microsoft of the obligation to conform to the [C# language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), see 7.12 Conditional logical operators.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I resolved this using the suggestion given by [Anders Abel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280222/anders-abel).

```
private IEnumerable<SubjectSelectorSubjectGroup> GetSubjectList()
{
    List<string> userSubjects = new List<string>();
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
        if (user.Elective1 != null) { userSubjects.Add(user.Elective1.SubjectId); }
        if (user.Elective2 != null) { userSubjects.Add(user.Elective2.SubjectId); }
        if (user.Elective3 != null) { userSubjects.Add(user.Elective3.SubjectId); }
    }

    return db.RequiredSubjects.Where(r => !r.Subject.Name.Contains("Home"))
                              .GroupBy(r => r.Subject)
                              .OrderByDescending(r => r.Count())
                              .Select(r => new SubjectSelectorSubjectGroup()
                              {
                                   SubjectId = r.Key.SubjectId,
                                   SubjectName = r.Key.Name,
                                   IsInFavourites = userSubjects.Contains(r.Key.SubjectId),
                                   Occurrences = r.Count()
                              });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of such behaviour is that your query is getting **translated to SQL** *(since its LINQ to SQL)*, and for `user.Elective` it is trying to generate a CASE statement. That is why you are getting the error.

Comment: Thanks, Habib, for the explanation of why my code was throwing the NULL exception.